# Getting the field issuedFor from SecurityIdentity using OIDC and KeyCloak

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, oid, quarkus-oidc

I am using OIDC and KeyCloak Quarkus extensions.

Currently, I access the token information like this:

```
@Inject org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken tokenMicroProfile;
@Inject SecurityIdentity securityIdentity;
```

I could not find the issuedFor field in these abstractions. This seems to have what I need.

```
@Inject org.keycloak.representations.JsonWebToken tokenKeyCloak;
```

But injection fails. So, how can I get the information using quarkus-oidc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `tokenMicroProfile.getClaim("azp")` or `tokenMicroProfile.getClaim(Claims.azp)`.